# Why did the staff at Hector's nursing home continue to admit Fring?

Tags: breaking-bad

Superficially, the idea seems to be that here is the helpless invalid who in addition to all of his health issues is made to periodically endure visits from Fring, his worst enemy.

But Hector not only uses a letter board to communicate complex sentences but is easily able to convey his displeasure and to give "yes" or "no" answers. So the staff could be made to understand that Hector did not want to see Fring if that was the case.

Is this explained? Could it be that despite his hatred for Fring, Hector still finds interesting and useful the things he says? Or is it possible that Fring has bribed whoever is in charge so that they continue to let Fring visit irrespective of Hector's feelings?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't find any actual statements from the writers to corroborate this, we do know that Hector is proud and sticks to his own (rather skewed) view of honour.

This is demonstrated by his refusal to look Gustavo in the eye. A point Gustavo explicitly calls out during that final encounter. Hector doesn't want Gustavo to think he is getting the upper hand. This includes making Gustavo feel that Hector is unmoved by his visits.

So, unpleasant for Hector as Gustavo's visits are, especially with the latter gloating about how his actions are undermining and finally destroying the Salamanca family, it would be a sign of weakness on Hector's part to ask the care home to deny Gustavo access.

> This eventually works in Hector's favour, allowing him (with Walter White's help) to kill Gustavo at the end.

Comment: maybe. but his visits have a very negative effect on hector which u wd think the staff wd observe.

Comment: But the nursing home staff know Hector can communicate, so they would probably not choose to exclude Gustavo without his consent, which Hector would not give. And they are probably well aware of Hector's character to think that he probably doesn't like anyone very much, so don't see his reaction to Gustavo as anything out of the ordinary.